# gRPC fails to find its own third-party source

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

I'm trying to use **cmake** instead of **bazel** to build **gRPC**。 However, the following **ERROR** messages received:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1055 (add_library):
   Cannot find source file:

     third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting.c

   Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
   .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc

 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3949 (add_library):
   Cannot find source file:

     third_party/upb/third_party/utf8_range/naive.c

   Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
   .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc

 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1055 (add_library):
   No SOURCES given to target: address_sorting

 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3949 (add_library):
   No SOURCES given to target: upb
```

However, clearly, both files exist:

```
➜  grpc git:(master) ✗ ll third_party/upb/third_party/utf8_range/naive.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lvision lvision 3.9K Mar  8 13:34 third_party/upb/third_party/utf8_range/naive.c
➜  grpc git:(master) ✗ ll third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting.c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lvision lvision 14K Mar  8 13:34 third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting.c
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: could it be a problem related to the path relative where you are running the cmake? As in your project is in `~/proj` then you are in `~/proj/bin` trying to run cmake from here, therefore it would be looking for the path at  `~/proj/bin/third_party......` instead of `~/proj/third_party.....` just a thought

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. Problem seems to be solved??
I actually build it **out from source** by

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
```

According to the official doc [gRPC C++ - Building from source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#build-from-source), this time, I tried

```sh
mkdir -p cmake/build
cd cmake/build
```

this seems to be okay... This doesn't seem to make sense. But, anyway, it's built now...